# Equivalent of sizeof(aType) in Go

Tags: c++, types, go, size, sizeof

C++ and several other languages have a function called `sizeof(int)` (or whatever type you need) that returns the number of bytes consumed by a particular data type, in the current system.

Is there an equivalent function in Go? What is it?

Comment: Please be aware that in Go, 99.9% of time this information is strictly useless (and that's why the `Sizeof` builtin is in the `unsafe` package) so if you're interested in this stuff you might be thinking of direct interpretation of some sequences of bytes coming from outside (of producing them). Unless you are an ace and really know what you're about to do, that's OK, but otherwise, please think thrice. Please refer to [this](http://commandcenter.blogspot.ru/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) dealing with a similar fallacy.

Comment: @kostix - I have a library for an in-memory dataSet that I wrote in C++ a long time ago - it uses a buffer of bytes to persist its data, and I use sizeof() to define buffer offsets. I'm replicating that library in Go - figure it will help me get into a lot of different areas quickly. But as I'm learning, the way I did it in C++ is probably not the Go way of doing things...

Comment: I have posted a summary of my thoughts on this as an answer (too short for a comment). Hope it will be useful somehow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to find out the size of a particular *value*, there are two ways to do that - using the unsafe package, or using the reflection package. The following code demonstrates both:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var i int
    fmt.Printf("Size of var (reflect.TypeOf.Size): %d\n", reflect.TypeOf(i).Size())
    fmt.Printf("Size of var (unsafe.Sizeof): %d\n", unsafe.Sizeof(i))
}
```

However, I am not aware of a way to get the size of a *type* directly. But I think you'll find out that the sizeof function is not needed as often as in C.

Answer (score 13):

The equivalent of `sizeof` in go is `unsafe.Sizeof`. One difference between it and sizeof in C is that it's only defined on values (whereas in C, it works for values and types). The other main difference is that in go it's hardly ever needed, whereas in C it's fairly common.

An example is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(int(0)))
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question: Not looking for the size of a particular value, although that will work by using a dummy value of the type needed.

Comment: @ComeAndGo: there is no equivalent to go directly from type definition to size without involving a value.  The answers you see here really are the closest equivalent to the C functionality.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge - Yes so I'm beginning to see - was reading about it today - outside of int/uint the sizes are clearly defined in the types and strings are strings. I guess where it's most relevant to me is date/time types. Have to learn some more.

Answer (score 10):

If you simply want to find out the size of an `int` or `uint`, use `strconv.IntSize`.

> [Package strconv](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> [Constants](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#pkg-constants)
>
> ```
> const IntSize = intSize
> ```
>
> `IntSize` is the size in bits of an `int` or `uint` value.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.Compiler, runtime.GOARCH, runtime.GOOS)
    fmt.Println(strconv.IntSize)
}
```

Output:

```
gc amd64 linux
64
```

Comment: Well, I see that's only defined for int or uint. I suppose because int32 and int64 and string are obvious...

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer but the continuation of the comments thread following the original question…

To implement an in-memory dataset, I would took one of these approaches:

- (Simple-minded): just use arrays of `interface{}` to store rows.

  Each value of interface type is a tuple of two pointers: a pointer to the enclosed value's real type and the value itself.  Implementation is `gc` (and `gccgo`, I beleive) is smart enough to store values directly in that pointer space if its size is ≤ the size of `uintptr` type on the target platform.
- (Supposedly more advanced): store type information for your columns in a separate data structure (an array or slice); the type information might be obtained with tools from the `reflect` package. Then store actual data in rows which are arrays of `unsafe.Pointer` and play the same trick the implementation of interfaces in `gc` does with values using type conversions from/to `unsafe.Pointer`.

  This would allow you to be more space-efficient by not storing a type of a value along with each contained value.  Not sure about real performance benefits, if any.

Comment: Approach 2 is what I did in C++  - then I just read the bytes @ the offset write them into a structure with the appropriate type - all predefined and delimited @ compile time, **very** fast @ runtime. It's essentially lifted from Delphi's TDataSet model - an array of 'fielddefs' and a generic array of bytes representing 'rows', each row laid out accord to the 'field defs' description.

Comment: @ComeAndGo, the chief idea here is to store arrays of `unsafe.Pointer`s rather than `byte`s -- this would possibly waste some space (but Go isn't Delphi and may work on platforms with strict alignment requirements) but gain ease of computation of offsets.

Comment: @ComeAndGo, it would be interesting to look at implementation--please consider publishing it (and announcing on golang-nuts)

Comment: _arrays of unsafe.Pointers rather than bytes_ - yeah that's the way it's done.  My intent was to publish it if I get designed and working satisfactorily, but I want it to be **Go**, not a port from C++ or Delphi.

Comment: @ComeAndGo, by the way, you might find looking at the [`ql`](https://github.com/cznic/ql) package interesting; in particular, its `mem.go` file.

Comment: yes I see - `ql` looks interesting... I am looking for something like that.

Comment: After poking around bit, I see that the key to doing this sort of thing correctly 'Go style' is to use slices with the `bytes` package - powerful stuff there.